# fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value while filtering

Tags: ios, uitableview, core-data, swift

I created a `TableViewController` to filter results from a CoreData database and I'm encountering this error when I attempt to implement the filter with the following `IBAction`. I've dug through the code checking for typos and I didn't spot any. Any assistance in figuring this out would be greatly appreciated, as I'm newish to programming:

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

@IBAction func saveButtonTapped(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    println("saveButtonTapped")
    delegate!.filterViewController(self,
        didSelectPredicate: selectedPredicate,
        sortDescriptor: selectedSortDescriptor)

    dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion:nil)
}
```

[image: Error]
[image: Error]

Here's the code for the TVC class:

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

protocol FilterViewControllerDelegate: class {
    func filterViewController(filter: RollerFilterViewController,
        didSelectPredicate predicate:NSPredicate?,
        sortDescriptor:NSSortDescriptor?)
}

class RollerFilterViewController: UITableViewController {

// outlet connected to cell on storyboard
    @IBOutlet weak var shoulderCell: UITableViewCell!
// Variables for filter
weak var delegate: FilterViewControllerDelegate?
var selectedSortDescriptor: NSSortDescriptor?
var selectedPredicate: NSPredicate?
var coreDataStack: CoreDataStack!

lazy var shoulderPredicate: NSPredicate = {
    var predicate = NSPredicate(format: "stretch.muscleGroup contains[cd] %@", "shoulder")
    return predicate!
    }()

// MARK - UITableViewDelegateMethods
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView,
    didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

        let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)!

        switch cell {
            // cases for muscle groups
        case shoulderPredicate:
            selectedPredicate = shoulderPredicate
        default:
            println("default case")
        }
        if cell.accessoryType == .Checkmark {
            cell.accessoryType = .None
            println("removed checkmark")
        } else {
            cell.accessoryType = .Checkmark
            println("set to checkmark")
        }
}
// MARK - UIButton target action

@IBAction func saveButtonTapped(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    println("saveButtonTapped")
    delegate!.filterViewController(self,
        didSelectPredicate: selectedPredicate,
        sortDescriptor: selectedSortDescriptor)

    dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion:nil)
}
}
```

Comment: Did you ever set the delegate?

Comment: "unexpectedly found nil" Believe the error. Something is nil. Use the debugger to find out what. As @rdelmar suggests, it is very probably `delegate`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this view controller called from or segued from another view controller? In that case, you should set the delegate property in the source's prepareForSegue method, or whatever mechanism is invoking this current view controller. Also, why is the protocol inheriting "class"? Is that the name of another protocol?

Regardless, your delegate is nil because it's never being set, and it seems that you should set it from the object invoking the view controller in question. Also take note that your delegate is weak, so unless another object has a strong reference to it, your delegate will be nil soon after it is assigned.

Comment: Thank you. This is my first "project" that's not a tutorial. I modeled the class from working code, but the example I used was backwards. I see where the problem is. I'm going to start over on the class and incorporate your info after spending the day reading documentation ;)

Answer (score 1):

I think you are trying to access delegate with out setting it and it is pointing to an object which is not yet created.Now delegate has a value as nil and the code becomes nil.(some property) which is meaning less so it prints that exception.Try it after setting the delegate and use "if let" which is better coding practice.

Comment: Thank you! I see what you're saying as I look at the output from the debug area. Can you dumb it down just a little more? What do I need to put where? Should it be inside the the IBAction or where the selectedSortDescriptor, selectedPredicate variables are introduced?

Comment: try setting the delegate in viewdidload as destinationcontroller.delegate = self;

Comment: well, it looks like his `delegate` property isn't getting set, not the destination controller's delegate. Try this in viewDidLoad:  `delegate = FilterViewControllerDelegate()`. Or whatever type your delegate is that conforms to that protocol.